# Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html, w3c-validation

My website seems good, have original design,responsive, compatible with every browser but the validator doesnt like my website.So, I want to pass its silly exam.It turned honour issue for me.

I havent two body tag but it says that:

```
Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open.

From line 748, column 5; to line 748, column 399

iv>↩↩↩    <body class="home page-template page-template-template-Blank page-template
```

http://www.hekim.deniz-tasarim.site/

https://validator.w3.org/

How can I "fix" it?

Answer (score -1):

you use wordpress so in  header.php of the theme file, wrap un-default lines with comment line markers then check again.You can learn the default lines in standart header.php from twentyseventeen theme.It is an example theme which relased from wordpress.

So, the question solved.You can check the website again.